# Call to a member function make() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm upgrading my project from laravel 4.2 to laravel 5 and when I try `composer update` after clear-compile command I get

```
Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on null...
```

and when I try to test my project, I get this:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the autoloader: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @craig_h I've tried that, no help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error message doesn't tell quite what is wrong. Check if your config files are ok and there are no unexpected tokens there. e.g. missing commas or closing brackets.